# State ownership cover everything for a class to be thread safe

Tags: java, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, multithreading, synchronization

As mentioned by [Java_author](https://www.amazon.ca/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Tim-Peierls-ebook/dp/B004V9OA84/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1),

> When defining which variables form an object's state, we want to consider only the data that object owns....
>
> In many case, ownership and encapsulation go together— **the object encapsulates the state it owns and owns the state it encapsulates**....
>
> A class usually does not own the objects passed to its methods or constructors, unless the method is designed to explicitly transfer ownership of objects passed in (such as the synchronized collection wrapper factory methods)...

---

For ensuring thread safety, a non-thread-safe class need to draw a line on the state variables that it owns to ensure thread safety. Those state variables can be populated in class through generalization, association, Dependency Injection and  what not.

My understanding is, Java author already gave(above) a **parameter** to assess state ownership for thread safety, *the object encapsulates the state it owns and owns the state it encapsulates*

**Edit after this [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358863/state-ownership-thread-safety#comment777642_358863):**

Below code taken from Listing 4.4/4.5 by [Java_author](https://www.amazon.ca/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Tim-Peierls-ebook/dp/B004V9OA84/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1),  See the `MonitorVehicleTracker` class below owning `locations` that are populated thru copy constructor,

```
package responsive;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class MutablePoint{
    public int x, y;
    
    public MutablePoint() {
        x=0; y=0;
    }
    
    public MutablePoint(MutablePoint p) {
        this.x = p.x;
        this.y = p.y;
    }
}

public class MonitorVehicleTracker {

    private final Map<String, MutablePoint> locations;
        
    public MonitorVehicleTracker( // Copy constructor
                        Map<String,MutablePoint> locations) {
        this.locations = deepCopy(locations);
        
    }
    
    public synchronized Map<String, MutablePoint> getLocations(){
        return deepCopy(locations);
    }
    
    public synchronized MutablePoint getLocation(String id) {
        
        MutablePoint loc = locations.get(id);
        return loc == null ? null : new MutablePoint(loc);
    }
    
    public synchronized void setLocation(String id, int x, int y) {
        MutablePoint loc = locations.get(id);
        if(loc == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such id: " + id);
        }
        loc.x = x;
        loc.y = y;
    }
    
    
    private static Map<String, MutablePoint> deepCopy(
            Map<String, MutablePoint> m){
        
        Map<String, MutablePoint> result = 
                    new HashMap<String, MutablePoint>();
        
        for(String id: m.keySet()) {
            result.put(id, new MutablePoint(m.get(id)));
        }
        
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
    }
    

}
```

that is used by GUI thread,

```
Map<String, Point> location = vehicles.getLocations();
for(String key: locations.keySet()){
   renderVehicle(key, locations.get)key));
}
```

and used by updater thread,

```
void vehicleMoved(VehicleMovedEvt evt){
   Point loc = evt.getNewLocation();
   vehicles.setLocations(evt.getVehicleId(), loc.x, loc.y);
}
```

---

For a non-thread-safe class to make thread-safe,

Do you agree with this **parameter** to apply *synchronization policy* on only those state variables that you own to ensure thread safety?

Comment: In #2, are you asking about, for example, container objects like arrays and vectors and trees? Or something else? Can you clarify?

Comment: @user1118321  For code  `class MyClass{ private HashSet<Person> mySet = new HashSet<Person>(); private int x;}`, Does object's state ownership involve just `x`, and `mySet` or state ownership involves `x`, `mySet` and `Person`? Here, `MyClass` has composition relationship with `HashSet<Person>`. Similarly `MyClass` may have aggregation relationship with some other class `Y`, not just collections

Comment: @user1118321 second point from java author in the query is most of its answer around, which says, *ownership and encapsulation go together-—the object encapsulates the state it owns and owns the state it encapsulates*

Comment: "A class usually does not own the objects passed to its methods or constructors" -- incorrect. Some objects are designed to represent complex data structures, whereby the objects passed to the constructor are always owned. Immutable objects in particular often use this technique. You cannot generalize to say "usually" in either case; it depends on the types of objects.

Comment: You should specify the type of data being "owned" and exactly what "owned" means. Is it immutable data? There is no need to control that, as it cannot be modified. But you need a root object to access it. If it is mutable data, ownership can mean release of resources, sole access to modify, or both.

Comment: Ownership is a real concept, but you cannot always tell by looking at a few classes what is owning what. You have to look at the application. Does the application keep only a single reference to a root object and only make calls on that object? That is a type of ownership. What is responsible for disposing resources? That is the type of ownership we usually refer to. The other type is not so important.

Comment: @FrankHileman Query edited for your comment

Comment: State is not "owned". State can be encapsulated: this refers to access control. If state is encapsulated, you can only get to it via an instance. For multithreading purposes, it means whatever external access you have to it is protected in some way: denied entirely, or some thread safe mechanism for mutating the state.

Comment: @FrankHileman Java author says: *the object encapsulates the state it owns and owns the state it encapsulates*

Comment: I should explain. If the state is encapsulated, is it "owned"? Nothing else can access it, so you might say it is "owned". You might say the ability to modify the state is "owned". But the correct term is "encapsulated". Ownership usually refers to the responsibility to dispose of resources.

Answer (score 2):

Don't over-conflate ownership with thread safety.  To make a class threadsafe, you have to make it threatsafe. No more.  No less.  This means:

- You cannot have two threads write to the same data at the same time
- You cannot have one thread write to the data and one thread read from it at the same time.
- The synchronization you add to the class does not violate any of the invariants of its methods (such as any guarantees of determinism).

Now it happens to be that encapsulation and ownership draw hard lines in the sand, and it can be easier to implement said threadsafety if you leverage these existing lines.  As an example, one of the concerns in making multithreaded code is deadlocks, where two threads contend for two locks in a way that prevents either from making progress.  If you put your synchronization at the edge of the encapsulated data, it becomes easy to prove that a particular class is deadlock free.

But ownership can't cover everything.   Consider that ownership means you can do anything you want with the data.  Read it, write it, store temporary copies of it.  It's yours.  In many multithreaded situations, you want many threads to be able to read the data simultaniously.  In order to do this, the "owner" must give up the right to write to that data until the reads are complete.  Generally speaking, our concept of "ownership" is not subtle enough to draw distinctions like this.

Comment: **1)** For your point: *ownership can't cover everything*. I disagree, because in the above code, class `MonitorVehicleTracker` own the state `locations` and its internal members(key, value). As part of this ownership, `MonitorVehicleTracker` should ensure thread safety for those owned states. With this, I can say `MonitorVehicleTracker` is thread safe. **2)** Btw, `MonitorVehicleTracker` does not own responsibility of adding new entry but, but `MonitorVehicleTracker` still owns state `locations` because for the reasons that `locations` need to be encapsulated by that class

Comment: @user1787812 Okay, I should be more precise.  You can come up with examples where the code is so simple that ownership can cover everything.  However, in the general case, it is more complicated.  That being said, I see you are using the `synchronized` keyword, which is a very simple tool for multithreading which only handles the pure ownership cases as you describe.  If that's the only tool you are using, then ownership will be a sufficient rule of thumb for ensuring safety (though you still need to make sure your multithreaded code doesn't violate any invariants)

Comment: When you say, *multithreaded code doesn't violate any invariants*. are you saying like? For a non-thread-safe *Stack* class, if stack is empty `pop()` simply returning `null`, make sense. For a thread-safe *Stack* class, if stack is empty then it make sense for `pop()` to  `wait()` instead of returning `null`, because another thread may `push()` anytime.

Comment: Documenting [Invariants](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/0_Java_basics/Language_features/cs61b/homework4/DList.java#L26) for every thread-safe class, for the state variables that a thread-safe class own, will cover every  scenario to be thread safe. This is what I understood from, when java author says,  *the object encapsulates the state it owns and owns the state it encapsulates*. Encapsulation is nothing but protecting invariants. Do you  still support that *ownership can't cover everything to be thread safe*?

Comment: An example for a thread-safe array may be that you can call `size()` to get the size of the array, and then call `get(n)` where n is an index smaller than `size` returned.  That may be an explicit invariant of your vector, or an implicit one.  When you add synchronization, you may find that the array size can change between calls to `size` and `get`, resulting in invalid code, even though you protected every state value that the object "owns" properly.  What happened was your user's code depended on things to stay the same when they, in fact, changed on another thread.

Comment: Say, `list` object is some thread-safe type list. But, still user(some class) having state `list`, should `lock(list); s = list.size(); n = s-2;y = list.get(n); unlock(list);` and perform a compound action with synchronization. This compound action will maintain one required invariant of state `list`. Here, the user(some class) owns state variable `list` to maintain thread safety. BTW, if `y` is actual mutable list member that is published to user, then `list` type has broken encapsulation, by publishing mutable state, in a threaded scenario

Comment: @user1787812 Then yes, you have made a threadsafe list.  As long as you never do anything more complicated (such as expose mutable members), you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, objects formed via composition own the data objects they are composed of generally. That in itself does not ensure thread safety, though. There are a few reasons:

1. The same object could be called on multiple threads, so it may actually make its own state inconsistent if you don't take proper precautions (such as using a mutex or similar construct)
2. If Object A owns Object B, but Object C asks for a reference rather than a copy of Object B, then both A & C may be able to modify Object B if you aren't careful.

You also ask:

> For code:
>
> ```
> class MyClass { 
>     private HashSet<Person> mySet = new HashSet<Person>(); 
>     private int x;
> }
> ```
>
> Does object's state ownership involve just x, and mySet or state ownership involves x, mySet and Person? Here, MyClass has composition relationship with HashSet.

I would say that `MyClass` owns `mySet` and `x` and that `mySet` owns each `Person` it contains. (So transitively `MyClass` also owns each `Person`.) This is all assuming that nobody else has strong references to these objects. (And in general only one object should ever have a strong reference to a given object.)

Comment: **1)** If you encapsulate a state variable then you own that state variable. A state variable can be `mySet`, or `Person` or `x`. For example, If you process/retrieve persons with encapsulation then you need to own `Person` state, before encapsulating that state variable. **2)** Wrt your point on *strong reference*, state ownership of `Person` in `MyClass` does not mean, class `Y` does not have state ownership on `Person`

Comment: 1) Yes, because if you don't own it, some other object could destroy it while you're trying to use it. 2) In general, it doesn't. But you need to be careful if multiple objects have a strong reference to a single object so that the shared object doesn't end up leaking memory. Using a reference counting scheme can help with that. My Java is a bit rusty, so I'm a little hazy on how strong references work there, otherwise I'd be more specific.

Comment: person  is member of hashset collection.  The same person can be part of someother collection. I own state,, it does not mean I create and destroy it, because some object created some where is my private member, as mentioned in my second question

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking here. It is possible for an object to have a weak reference to other objects. In that case you may not be creating and destroying them. I would still consider them part of your state, though, if your object is holding weak references to them.